# AES file encryption with .Net Framework and decrypt it with IOS

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, encryption, aes

We encrypt PDFs using AESManaged algorithm implemented in .NET framework. I used the example explained in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) to implement C# code to encrypt the file. Now I need to decrypt that file using an iPhone application.(That is the requirement). So I use the [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html) code to do that but decryption failed by returning an error.

> 'Error Domain=CommonCryptoErrorDomain Code=-4304 "Decode Error"
>   UserInfo=0x127356c0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Input data did not
>   decode or decrypt correctly, NSLocalizedDescription=Decode Error'

Can some one help me to resolve this issue.

We use 12345678 as encryption key.

Comment: So which error it returns?

Comment: It says 'Error Domain=CommonCryptoErrorDomain Code=-4304 "Decode Error" UserInfo=0x127356c0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Input data did not decode or decrypt correctly, NSLocalizedDescription=Decode Error'

Comment: @ganuke Don't post important information as a comment. Please edit your question and add the error.

Comment: You can't use `12345678` as encryption key. AES takes a 16, 24 or 32 byte sequence, but that is a string.

Comment: I found [this](http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2009/02/12/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone/) and successfully able to integrate in to our system. Thanks Every one

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in the deriving actual key from the password (12345678 cannot be the AES key directly - it is only 8 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should work though I've never tested it, both methods uses the same ad-hoc format.

Encrypt using my authenticated encryption [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366194/637783).

```
//use your secret data you want to encrypt instead.
String secretMessage = "Message";

var rnCryptorHeader = new Byte[]{
                            2, //RNCryptor Format version 2
                            0  //RNCryptor Uses password
                        };

//encryptedString is base64 encoded
var encryptedString = AESThenHMAC.SimpleEncryptWithPassword(secretMessage, 
                                                            password:"1234567891011",      
                                                            nonSecretPayload:rnCryptorHeader);
```

Then Decrypt using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) and [NSData+Base64](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64) for IOS

```
//This is the encrypted data passed from .net
NSString *encryptedString = @"AgE8C9E7gsfyOAmSotIOgyLQ0O6mdcuMXXjN/iZa3azym4KVWZAkfykIP6mqMt/qkpfftdB3XQhMkoxtQEM+rA0iHxOvZiNlmA2KJtg6BOnmlg==";

NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataFromBase64String: encryptedString];
NSError *error;
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                                    withPassword:@"1234567891011"
                                           error:&error];
NSString *secretMessage = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Since you aren't dealing with strings and are dealing with bytes directly, just remove the Base64 and utf8 encoding/decoding from this objective-c example and the linked c# example, once you are sure this is working.